# vba : alloting a range to an array and then multiplying that range

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ary(2, 2) As Variant

    For p = 0 To 2
        For q = 0 To 2
            ary(p, q).Value = Range("a1:c3")
        Next q
    Next p

    For f = 0 To 2
        For t = 0 To 2
            Cells(f + 1, t + 5).Value = ary(f, t) * 2
        Next t
    Next f
End Sub
```

I am writing the above program to allot a range to the array. but it is showing an error called object required. when i try to debug it is selecting the statement

**ary(p, q).Value = Range("a1:c3")**

can some one help ???

Comment: That is an incorrect way to store a range to an array. Try this `Dim MyAr As Variant` and then `MyAr = Range("a1:c3").Value`

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ary As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

    ary = ws.Range("a1:c3")

    For f = 1 To UBound(ary)
        For t = 1 To UBound(ary)
            Cells(f + 1, t + 5).Value = ary(f, t) * 2
        Next t
    Next f
End Sub
```